# Install Without Manufacturer Name - Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

Is there a way to install my application without a manufacturer name using a Visual Studio Setup Project?

For example, if in the setup project properties I leave the manufacturer name blank, it installs to

```
C:/Program Files/Default Company Name/ApplicationName
```

my desired install location is

```
C:/Program Files/ApplicationName
```

How can I install to a directory without using the Manufacturer name field at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the default location property of the Application folder by taking the following steps:

1. Right-click on your setup project, select > `View` > `File System`
2. Select `Application Folder` in the tree
3. In the Visual Studio menu, select `View` > `Properties Window`
4. Edit the `Default Location` field. In my case I changed it to `[ProgramFilesFolder]\[ProductName]`

Now your application will be installed to the program files directory without an additional Manufacturer folder.